# Selenium unable to interact with any element on a "ng-view" screen

Tags: python, selenium, ng-view

[image]

I'm trying to click on the "Reserve Now" button with the following code:

```
button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'Button')
button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'Button--primary')
button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'Button--lg')
button.click()
```

It always returns an error stating:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
> element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css
> selector","selector":".Button--lg"}

I also tried other basic interactions such as simply printing a text element and it always returns the error. I tried putting a time.sleep(10) just to make sure things had time to load and it still causes an error.

What's odd is that I'm not doing anything different than the rest of my code before reaching this point. I'm guessing that screen specifically has something blocking Selenium or something of the sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That button has a `data-test-id`, which is probably placed there to help you automate it. Use:

```py
button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[data-test-id="order_summary_page-button-book"]')
button.click()
```

Or for better reliability:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

# ... ... ...

button = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[data-test-id="order_summary_page-button-book"]')))
button.click()
```

Comment: Both methods give errors. The first one says that the element is not found, the second one gives a time-out error.

Comment: Is the element in an iframe? (Only part of the HTML is shown.) If there's an iframe, you must switch to it first.

Comment: How can I detect if it's an iframe?

Comment: In the HTML, there would be an ``iframe`` tag somewhere above the element.

Comment: Ok, I found an iframe src that basically highlights that entire block. Do I basically driver.get() that link and then use the commands above?

Comment: ``driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector(css_selector))``

Comment: If it's the only iframe on the page:
``driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("iframe"))``